# Adding an extra dependency in new Rules to existing Rules

Tags: haskell, shake-build-system

I am writing a Shakefile with the aim of making it extensible with new `Rules`. Its interface is a function `mainFor :: Rules () -> IO ()`, the idea being that client projects would only need to define `main = mainFor myCustomRules` to get the whole thing working. `mainFor customRules` is defined as a bunch of Shake `Rules` followed by a call to `customRules`.

This works as long as the custom rules passed to `mainFor` are for new targets.

However, some of my stock (non-custom) rules are basically of the form "run this big opaque proprietary external script with this input and hope for the best"; and there can be extra files used by the external script depending on its input. For example, imagine I have a rule of the following form:

```
"_build/output.bin" %> out -> do
    need ["_build/script.scr", "_build/src/generated.src"]
    runExternalScript
```

For a particular client project, maybe the generated source code contains references to another file `_build/src/extrainput.src`. So in the custom rules passed to `mainFor`, not only do I need extra rules for this file, but the existing rule should also be modified to mark that it `need`s this input:

```
main = mainFor $ do
    "_build/src/extrainput.src" %> \out -> do
       generateExtraSrc

    "_buld/output.bin" %> \out -> do
      need ["_build/src/extrainput.src"]
```

but this, unsurprisingly, fails because both the stock rule in `mainFor` and the second custom  rule passed in the `customRules` argument are for the same target. **Note that I do not want to fully override the stock rule, only extend it to add the extra dependency.**

Comment: You could introduce an intermediate target `Key` for "extra_input.txt" that could generate a file list in a file called "extra_input.txt". For your standard build, the contents of that file might be empty but for your special targets, it will add the necessary dependencies. We would need more context from your shake file to suggest where to put the intermediate `Key`.

Comment: @BobDalgleish but that sounds like it would only work with pre-selected explicit extension points. I'm more looking for a solution where `mainFor` doesn't have to anticipate which rules would be possibly extended this way in various clients.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to do this using Shake. The possibilities are:

- Add it to Shake. Whether that's the right thing depends on how common this requirement is - and my guess is relatively rare - but that needs validating. The fact you want the dependencies run before the rule is more concerning - it's somehow less compositional than just providing multiple actions that together produce a result.
- Do it on the outside. My straw man would be to write the "extras" as some kind of `FilePath -> Action ()` function, then define your own `%>` that also applied that function to the output. It would only work with pre-selected extension points, but if you redefine `%>` at the top of the file it can hit all your instances.
- If you really want to hide it more, use `shakeExtra` to store the state in some way.

Comment: That's a shame; I've found Make's similar functionality useful in the past.

Comment: Is "providing multiple actions that together produce a result" something that Shake already supports?

Comment: No, shake doesn't support putting multiple actions together at the moment.